# Terminal won't choose new window settings at startup

Tags: macos, terminal

I've been running into an odd behavior on 10.7 where editing Terminal preferences to launch a new window setting via "On startup, open" doesn't result in the changed terminal after a quit/launch.

Any idea what I may be doing wrong and/or how to trigger the new style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like Lion's resume feature is confusing the cause-effect relationship between settings and application behavior.

The "On Startup, open" *should* work, assuming that you had no windows open when you closed Terminal.app.  Lion's resume feature is enabled for Terminal.app by default, so quitting the application before closing any windows will yield the same windows the Terminal is re-launched.

The simplest fix is this:

1. Make sure you've closed all Terminal windows.
2. Restart Terminal.app.

In the normal course of events, the resulting window should have the "On Start, open..." settings. If the steps above do not fix the issue, then I recommend deleting your Terminal preferences with a backup so that you can revert if needed.

---

**Disable Resume for Terminal.app**

You can also just disable resume for Terminal.app. Run the following command and re-launch Terminal.app *twice*:

```
defaults write com.apple.Terminal NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows -bool false
```

Comment: Yup, it was that simple of an issue. I would always leave a terminal or two open before restart. Thanks for the thorough details & cli fix.